# why do many utilities specify network data rate in bytes/s rather than bits/s

Tags: networking, network-programming

Most utilities I've used that take a network data rate limit (e.g. torrent client), do so in bytes/s rather than bits/s. Typically I know how much bandwidth I want to consume in bits/s not bytes/s, so have to perform the conversion myself which I find error prone (forget whether to multiply or divide, or forget altogether).

Why don't more utilities use bits/s, or at least have the option of specifying either bytes/s or bits/s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes down to differences between the people building networking equipment  - electrical engineers, whose education is based in physics, and the people writing networking software - software engineers, whose education is based in computer science.

Electrical engineers think in terms of bit/second, and [powers of 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix) (K = 1000, M=1000000 etc). Computer scientists think of file sizes, in bytes and [powers of 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix) (K = 1024, M = 1048576 etc). Software engineers also tend to think of useful data throughput, as opposed to line rate, so they don't care how many bits per second can be send over a line; they're more interested in how many bytes of actual data can be sent over that line without the various overhead involved.

Comment: Basically, the difference between bandwidth and throughput.